# C# Microsoft Identity authentication

Tags: c#, azure, authorization, blazor

We currently have an Azure Active directory used for external applications authentication.
I've set up a sample project using the Visual Studio Blazor server template that uses our AD and Microsoft authentication.
It works fine but I would like to manage the authorization (roles, users) in my own application instead of Azure AD. By manage, I mean having the roles and users UI definition in my own app even if roles and users could be stored in the Azure AD
Could you link me some code samples where the authorization frontend is designed within the app?

Comment: Hello @Milad Dastan Zand,
I have tested Microsoft Graph but with limited access since Applications, Roles required admin consent that i don't have yet.

Comment: I'm also looking for alternatives where authorizations are handled in the app with no definition in AD.

Comment: Hi, nice to see you, welcome to community

Comment: I think the rickvdbosch Answer has good points @NicolasN

Answer (score 0):

If I translate your question into: how can I manage users and roles in Azure Active Directory from my own application, my answer would be to have a look at [Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview), for instance by having a look at the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) to see how it works.

> Microsoft Graph is the gateway to data and intelligence in Microsoft 365. It provides a unified programmability model that you can use to access the tremendous amount of data in Microsoft 365, Windows 10, and Enterprise Mobility + Security. Use the wealth of data in Microsoft Graph to build apps for organizations and consumers that interact with millions of users.
>
> [image]